# array of promises containing cassandra queries not triggering well

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, es6-promise

I'm currently trying to fill a cassandra table with the content of an xlsx file, but I'm facing a problem.

I managed to do an array with all the queries necessary to fill my table ("insert into my_table (values name, ...) values (values, ...);" ).
So my array got like 7000 strings.

I'm then doing a promise and inside this promise I made a loop to fill and array of promises in order to trigger the first promise when all the promises are over.

this is the code I made

index.js

```
const ImportFileContent = require("./scripts/import_file_content")
const InsertDb = require("./scripts/insertDb")

const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const databaseConfig = require('./config/database.json');

const authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider(databaseConfig.cassandra.username, databaseConfig.cassandra.password);

const db = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: databaseConfig.cassandra.contactPoints,
    authProvider: authProvider
});


// ImportFileContent.importFileContent return an array of string, those strings contains all the 7000+ queries
ImportFileContent.importFileContent().then(queries => {
    InsertDb.clients(db, queries).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
         db.shutdown(function (err, result) {
        });
    });
});
```

insertDb.js

```
let DB = null;

module.exports = {
    ClientsLeasing: function (db, queries) {
        DB = db;
        return insertClientsLeasing(queries);
    }
}

function insertClientsLeasing(queries) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let nbError = 0;
        let nbSuccess = 0;
        let promisesArray = [];
        //I made i <2000 here because my cassandra setup doesn't manage more than 2048 request in parallele
        for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            promisesArray.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                DB.execute(queries[i], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        nbError++;
                        reject(err)
                    } else {
                        nbSuccess++;
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }));
        }
        Promise.all(promisesArray).then((result) => {
            console.log("is over")
            console.log("over ===================== success => ", nbSuccess, "                    errors => ", nbError);
            resolve("success");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            console.log("is over error")
            console.log("over ===================== success => ", nbSuccess, "                    errors => ", nbError);
            resolve("error");
        });

    });
}
```

My table has two primary keys the creation date (which is now()) and the client id that may be in multiple rows of the xlsx (that can be the source of the problem ?).

So now when I launch this code my output is [image]

then when I do a count in the table via cqls I only get 1962 rows with this output
[image]

I feel like I'm missing something in the way I use my promises. I don't really get it.

Thanks

Comment: please add the table schema, and queries that you execute - it could be that your primary key definition isn't correct, and you simply overwrite the data...

Comment: the table i'm trying to insert the value has two primary keys, the date of insert (now()) and a client id. that client id may be in multiple rows, is that the source of the problem ? I thought now was used to create uuid ? here it's just for the date but it's used in the primary key.

I'm working with an existing table and i can't really change it

Comment: ok so you were right the problem was that i overwrited some data. thanks for the help :)